# What should be MySQL query for the following?

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to show upcoming birthday records on dashboard. I have MySQL table 'contacts' which

has field `dob (DATE YYYY-MM-DD)`. I want to retrieve all the records with birthday is coming

in next 15 days. e.g is: birthday is 1986-03-24 it should be in result.

Comment: try INTERVEL on mysql

Comment: Dipesh Parmar's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at MySQL `DATE_ADD` and `INTERVAL`.

By using both as below you can get record that are coming in next 15 days.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE dob BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

FOR birthrate comparison.

```
MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 15 DAY), DAYOFYEAR(birthday)) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 15 DAY
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d77/2)

Comment: this will not complete work. because dates have year, example, today is `March 14, 2013`, I was born on `March 16, 1990`, how will my birthday be in the result list?

Comment: That's because your query is also taking the year into consideration

Comment: Please take birth year into consideration.

Comment: @JW. thanx for correction i did not realized that...corrected it

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't you take only Month and Day into consideration?

Comment: @asprin yes you are right there are other ways to OP can use DATE_FORMAT use between clause too..

Comment: `+1` use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` and it will work, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d77/2

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the date in mysql query as:

```
 SELECT FROM table_name WHERE timestamp_row BETWEEN 
    '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-01-02 23:59:59';
```

You are doing the B'Day dates of users and thus hope this would be do the trick of formatting and selection of date

```
select id from my_table
 where
 timestamp < date_format(date_add(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), interval 1 day),
         '%Y%m%d000000' ) AND timestamp >=  date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
         '%Y%m%d000000')
```

Can do by this way also

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE IF  ( MONTH( NOW() ) < 12, 
     MONTH( birthdate ) = MONTH( NOW() ) + 1, MONTH( birthdate ) = 1)
```

Comment: this will not complete work. because dates have year, example, today is `March 14, 2013`, I was born on `March 16, 1990`, how will my birthday be in the result list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. Try Out

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE REPLACE(BirthDate, DATEPART(YEAR, BirthDate), DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())) BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 15, GETDATE())
```